# SDM API calls are returning Enterprise not found

Tags: google-api, google-sdm-api

I'm calling the SDM API using the google-api-nodesj-client package, and receiving an Enterprise not found message when I try to set the temperature.

The API returns a 404 on the nest.enterprises.devices.executeCommand call with the following error block :

> message: 'Enterprise enterprises/long-enterprise-id-here not found.',
> domain: 'global',
> reason: 'notFound'

```
async function setTemp(device_name, tempFahrenheit) {

    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sdm.service']
    });

    const authClient = await auth.getClient();
    const nest = await google.smartdevicemanagement(
    {
        version: 'v1',
        auth: authClient,
    });

    // Do the magic
    try {
        const res = await nest.enterprises.devices.executeCommand({
            name: device_name,
            requestBody: {
                "command" : "sdm.devices.commands.ThermostatTemperatureSetpoint.SetHeat",
                "params" : {
                    "heatCelsius" : getCelcius(tempFahrenheit)
                }
            }
        });
        console.log(res.data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.dir(e);
    }

}
```

I haven't found anything in the SDM documentation that alludes to this error. It *feels* like a GCP service account configuration issue but I can't make sense of it.

Comment: I've gone through the quick start guide linked from the Device Access Console and verified that I have access to the device. I've also verified that I can get data flowing through PubSub and hitting a GCP Function! I'm assuming I can also access the device from the API using a service account. Perhaps a bad assumption?

Comment: I've found API error documentation - https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/errors/api - and this error indicates that the Project ID is not correct. I've verified I'm passing the correct device_name here which includes the correct project ID.

Comment: Where did you get your enterprise id from?

Comment: @searlea it's the project ID in the Device Access Console. And it's also returned to me in the payload of events that get routed via PubSub

Comment: OK.  It's just I've seen Enterprise ID labelled as Customer ID in some places, Organisation ID in others, but can't remember ever seeing it as Project ID.

Comment: Hey @Greg, did you figure this out? I'm in exactly the same position now. I know for a fact this API call should work because it works just fine when I use my personal account getting the oauth access token, but when I try and use the service account it is not able to see the same enterprise/project. I get a 404.

Comment: @Vizzyy never did and the project is sitting unfinished.

Comment: Same issue here. Turned out I cannot do this with a service account, I need to do this with an oauth2 token. Also, the OAuth client ID should be filled into the Device Access Console at https://console.nest.google.com/device-access/